# Find a number M such that $\mid x^3 - x^2 +8x \mid\leq M$ for all $-2\leq x \leq 10$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find a number M such that $\mid x^3 - x^2 +8x\mid \leq M$ for all $-2\leq x \leq 10$

I am not sure my answer is right or not..

I used triangle inequality.

$\mid x^3 - x^2 +8x\mid \leq \mid x^3 \mid + \mid x^2  -8x \mid  \leq \mid x^3 \mid + \mid x^2 \mid + \mid 8x \mid $

$M = 10^3 + 10^2 + 8(10)$

Comment: Good job, that's a great approach.

Comment: Is this right way to solve it ? ..?

Comment: There are others, but this is one. If there is supposed to be a "right" answer only your teacher would be able to tell you what he/she is looking for.

Comment: Or, you could use Calculus to find the max and min values of $x^3-x^2+8x$ on the interval $[-2,10]$.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the best result |$ 10^3 - 10^2 +8*10$|?[see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm1UY.png)